# Create users with email an phone provider using Admin Firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

How can one create a user with phone number and email as providers in Firebase?

The code presented only sets up the phone number as being the only provider.

[image]

admin.auth().createUser({

```
uid: email,
email: email,
emailVerified: true,
phoneNumber: checkMobileTel(mobileTel)
```

})
  .then(function(userRecord: { uid: any; }) {

```
// See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
console.log('Successfully created new user:', userRecord.uid);
```

})
  .catch(function(error: any) {

```
console.log('Error creating new user:', error);
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are forgetting to add the password field. I hope I could help, happy coding!

> `password string` The user's raw, unhashed password. Must be at least six characters long.